Which one is more restricted CNF or GNF
I think that CNF should be more restricted due to its format rather than GNF.
CNF has more restricted format compared to GNF

What do you mean by 'restricted'? Both are equally powerful since you can represent all CFGs with either of them.

In fact Chomsky normalform and Greibach normalform are incomparable: neither one is implied by the other. Let us review the definitions.

ChNF: every production is of one of two forms, either $A\to BC$ or
$A\to a$, where $A,B,C$ are nonterminals and $a$ is terminal.
GrNF: every production is of the form $A\to a\alpha$, where $A$ is
nonterminal, $a$ is terminal and $\alpha$ is an arbitrary sequence of
nonterminals.

Each of these normalforms have their own advantage. ChNF results in a binary derivation tree. GrNF is special since each left-to-right derivation step adds exactly one terminal. They are structurally incomparable: productions like $A\to BC$ and $A\to aB$ are of one type but not the other. On the other hand the normalforms are equilly powerful. For every context-free language which does not derive the empty string there is both a grammar in ChNF and in GrNF. (That is why they can be called normalforms.)
GrNF is considered to be more complex to obtain than ChNF. And the constructions I know convert into ChNF first. Nevertheless, GrNF is not a  'restricted' version of ChNF.
